# How does the response.url know which url we're requesting?(Scrapy)

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, response

```
class PostsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "posts"

    start_urls = ["https://blog.scrapinghub.com/pages/1/",
                  "https://blog.scrapinghub.com/pages/2/"]

    def parse(self, response):
        page=response.url.split('/')[-1]
```

I've just started Scrapy and I am very confused about on the last line where it says respons.url.split . I understand that it's telling the url to split 1 place from backward but I cant seem to understand how the response.url knows which url we're requesting since our url is under the variable 'start_urls' but we're not refrencing 'start_urls'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that when you define the class you are creating a child class of `scrapy.Spider`, therefore inheriting the methods and attributes of the parent class.

```
class PostsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
```

This parent class has a method called `start_requests` ([source code](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/_modules/scrapy/spiders.html#Spider.start_requests)) that will use the URLs defined in the class variable `start_urls` to create requests. When a `Request` object is created it carries a callback function. That is the function that will be called when Scrapy Engine receives a response for the request.

The default callback function is called `parse`, that's why you are expected to implement a function named `parse` that will parse the response in your spider.

When called, this callback function receives an argument named `response`. That is nothing more than an object containing all the information regarding the response of the request, including what was the URL you made the request. (the `response.url` attribute)